# Backpack/Laravel CRUD no "Add new"

Tags: php, laravel, crud, laravel-backpack

I have installed Backpack/Laravel in my project, evrything works well so far, but not when I tried to add a new "Product" it throws the MasAssignamentException:

> MassAssignmentException in Model.php line 232:
>   nombre

Where "nombre" is the field in my database, I know that is because Laravel needs de `$fillabe` variable, but where to set it or where to configure that to not getting that error.

Comment: Read this http://anytch.com/laravel-5-mass-assignment-guarded-vs-fillable/2/

Comment: Can you please post the code in line number 232 of your Model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your model .. you should have a fillable variable .. like

```
protected $fillable = [
    'nombre', 'somefield',
];
```

Comment: I noticed that Backpack creates a new directory called Models in which it creates its owns Models, so there I added the fillable variables and it worked, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Need to go to your model and add nombre field to protected $fillable

protected $fillable = ['nombre'];